# Checking an array of fields for a repeated word

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an array of words and an array of input fields, after entering a word and then clicking on the button, a search will be performed in the array of words. It should also be checked that the words are not repeated, i.e. if the word has already been written, then it should not be used again. I wrote this code, but here's how to make it checked for repetition of the word I don't know, please tell me how it can be done?

```
string[] Array_words= new string[] { "Dot", "Life", "World", "Tree"};

public void Done()
{
    
    foreach (InputField inputField in InputFields)
    {
        string[] ArrayW= inputField.text.Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < Array_words.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (string s in ArrayW)
            {
                if (s.Contains(Array_words[i]))
                     Debug.LogFormat($"OK");

            }
        }
    }
   
}
```

And please tell me how you can implement a check for the emptiness of all fields, i.e. if all the fields are empty, then he writes a message in the Log, tried like this, but still outputs a message even if it is written in one field.

```
 foreach (InputField inputField1 in InputFields)
    {
     t=inputField1.text;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
    {
        Debug.LogFormat($"field is Empty!");

    }
```

Comment: I suppose your `IsNullOrEmpty`-check should be **within** the loop, shouldn't it? Currently it just checks the very last inputfield.

Comment: *if the word has already been written, then it should not be used again* - does it really matter to prevent the user doing that, or would it be simpler to just dedupe it? `inputField.text.Split().Distinct()`? If you only wish to know that the user has typed only words that are in the array, do we even care about duplicates? `inputField.text.Split().All(Array_words.Contains)` ? (It means "the words in the inputfield are all contained in the array_words" -> user can type "Dot Dot Dot Dot Dot" if they want..

Comment: @CaiusJard, Unfortunately, I still need to do a check for repeated words, I tried what you advised me "input Field.text.Split().Distinct()". But an error occurs: "error CS1061: 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Distinct' and no accessible extension method 'Distinct' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)", not please tell me how can I fix it?)

Comment: `using System.Linq` at the top of the file, or point to the wiggly red line for a moment and then click on the lightbulb button that appears

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, I tried to write in the array, but still the message "the field is empty" was displayed on each line, even if one word was entered. And I need to make sure that only with all empty fields a message is displayed...

Comment: @CaiusJard, Now he writes: "error CS0266: It is not possible to implicitly convert the type 'System.Collections.General.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. There is an explicit conversion (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Put `.ToArray()` after `Distinct()`

Comment: @CaiusJard, Hmm... there are no errors now, but what has changed?  I did not succeed without repetitions ;-( i.e. if I enter the same word again, then everything is output to the log two OK

Comment: What are you entering?

Comment: (The inputfield words will be deduped within themselves, but they are not deduped across different fields, and deduping is case sensitive. If you want to dedupe across fields, store words into a hashset. If you want case insens, its perhaps easiest to lowercase all the words first)

Comment: @CaiusJard, Well, I entered in 2 fields, 2 words "Dot". I thought that one thing would be output to the log: Ok.

Comment: The dedupe process is done per field, because that's how the loop is structured

Comment: @CaiusJard, and how to do it for everyone, and not for each individual field, please tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deduping across every field:

```
string[] Array_words= new string[] { "Dot", "Life", "World", "Tree"};

public void Done()
{
    //dedupe all fields
    var hs = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (InputField inputField in InputFields)
      hs.UnionWith(inputField.text.Trim().Split());

    //prohibit all fields blank
    if(hs.Count == 1 && hs.First() == "") throw new InvalidOperationException("All fields are blank");

    //check all entered words are present in Array_words
    var allOk = hs.All(Array_words.Contains);
   
}
```

Note that C# is case sensitive by default. `dot` and `Dot` are different things